# Need help with these invasive vines damaging trees causing tree limbs to break

Tags: species-identification, botany

I need some help identifying various vines growing and girdling trees:

[image]

Comment: Please review the [guidelines](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) for writing a good species-identification question. At the very least, you should include your location, the size of your vines, and any closeup images you can (including any you may have of any of the vines' leaves). Please update to enable a good answer (and to avoid having your question downvoted and closed). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like Kudzu from afar. Very hard to manage,IMO , but not impossible. Cut and apply systemic herbicide to the cut stems, perhaps. You'll need to hit the growth a few times, otherwise all you can do is cut it back and wait for it to re-grow.